# Adding items to cart in react js

Tags: reactjs

In reactjs, what code would I have to write in my two components(homepage.js with an add-to-cart button and a checkout page with a clear cart button? This is my Homepage.js where I fetch the items from my backend server, map, and display them on the page.

```
function Home() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      // auto-login
      fetch("/coffees").then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          res.json().then((data) => setData(data))
        }
      });
    }, [])
    console.log(data)

    return (
    <>
    <div className="box">
        <div className="projo">
        <h2 >Welcome to Coffee-cafe</h2>
        </div>
            <div className="projects">
             {data.map((data) =>{
              return(
                <div className="card">
                    <img className="avatar" src={data.coffee_image} alt="coffee"></img>
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <h4><b>{data.coffee_name}</b></h4>
                        <p id="desc">{data.description}</p>
                        <p className="price">{data.price}</p>
                        {/* <p>{data.category}</p> */}
                        <button onClick={() => ({})} className="btn1" id="btn1">Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )
            })}
            </div>    
    </div>

    </>

       
    )
}

export default Home;
```

For the Checkout.js, this is what I have currently.

```
function Checkout() {
    return (
        <>
         <div className="section">
       <div className="photo">
           <img className="dp" src={image1} alt="coffee"></img>
           <div className="info">
               <h3>Coffee:</h3>
               <p>Price:</p>
               <p>Category:</p>
               <div className="check-out-btn">
                   {/* <button className="add">AddToCart</button> */}
                   <button className="delete">ClearCart</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I use a context for it. I would post the comment here, but I can't post it unless I answer, and I'm not sure if my code will be what you're looking for. Here's a pastebin  just in case you want to peruse it. :)

https://pastebin.com/u5RqUe22

Comment: Thanks joe, helped me get an idea of what I'm supposed to do

Comment: If adding cart and checkout is the only functionality in your project, Setup an array, push your items in it, if your business requirement is not to retain the data on page refresh, you keep using the array, and pass the data in checkout as props. But if you need to keep the cart items on page refresh and also they will be going to use on other pages as well, use react redux or context.

Answer (score 0):

take a look for a global states like redux , context,or zustand
for my recommendation, I suggest zustand is less code than context and redux and short learning curve

```
carts =[]

setItemToCart(item){
const isExist = carts.find(c => c.id ===item.id)
if(isExit){
  const qty = isExit.qty+item.qty
  const newItem= {...item,qty}
  // push is not recommended to use because it mutates state
  carts.push(newItem)
}else{
  carts.push(item)
}
}
```